# How to overcome empty queryset clone issue in tastypie?

Tags: python, api, rest, tastypie

I am trying to create a REST API, but I'm facing the below issue:

> /tastypie/resources.py", line 1475, in get_object_list
>        return self._meta.queryset._clone()
>    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_clone'

---

```
class ManageResource(ModelResource):

   class Meta(ModelResource.Meta):
       resource_name = 'resourceStatus'
       detail_allowed_methods = ['get']
       always_return_data = True
       default_format = 'application/json'

    def base_urls(self):
       return [
           url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, 
               trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('dispatch_list'), 
               name="api_dispatch_list"),
           url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<request_id>[\w\d_.-]+)%s$"
            % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
            self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'), name="api_dispatch_detail"),
        ]

    def get_detail(self, request, **kwargs):
        id = int(kwargs["request_id"])
        return self._get_response(request, self.obj_get(request=request,id=id))

    @obj_wrapper
    def obj_get(self, request, id):
       result = Helper().status(id=id)    
       return {"info":{"start_time":result.get("start_time"),\
            "end_time":result.get("end_time"),\
            "status":result.get("status"),\
            "messages":result.get("messages")}}
```

I haven't set queryset in the meta class, since I pull data from a file or some kind of static resource.

Comment: Ummm can you show your code?

Comment: @qwertynl : included the code in desc, pls let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `queryset` field to your resource's `Meta`. If you are not using the standard `QuerySet`, override `get_object_list` method.

Comment: Thanks for your time in answering this, the reason why I am not using query set is because, response "json" string will get created as part of obj_get method and I thought there is no need to go with query set. Is it really mandatory to define query set ? Once again thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Since you are not using any models in your resource, I suggest the regular `Resource` class. Set `obj_get` to return the `Helper()...` result. Add `info` field to that resource, of type `fields.DictField` and fill it in `dehydrate_info`. This way you are separating much of the logic where it should belong to, and leaving space for extension.

Comment: Thanks @kroolik!! My bad the issue is due to indentation, due to this tastypie is trying to execute the parent implementation instead of actual method in my resource. :(

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I accomplished this:

```
class SomeFakedResource(Resource):
    # list out your fields as usual
    test_quantity = fields.IntegerField(attribute='test_quantity')

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'some_faked'
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        include_resource_uri = False

    def _calculate_test_quantity(self):
        # here's where I put the real work of calculating the field
        return 1

    def obj_get_list(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        return self.get_object_list(bundle.request)

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        self.test_quantity = self._calculate_test_quantity()
        return [self]
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Martin!